# How do I change a value of a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to change the attribute values number and a in myfun with certain calling times.
But I fails by just setting number and a as an attribute of this class.
So how do I change the value of a with every ten times calling and upgrade number by different value a?

I try the callback mechanism and directly change the value outside the myfunction, but it does not affect the computation in myfunction.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = K.variable(0, dtype='int64')
        self.a = K.variable(1,dtype='int64')
        self.myfun = self.myfunction(callbacks = self.changed)

    def myfunction(self, callbacks):
        if self.number % 10 == 0:
            self.a = callbacks()
        self.number += self.a
        train  = K.function([],[self.number], updates=[self.number, self.a])
        return train
    def changed(self):
        self.a *= 10
        return self.a
a = A()
print(a.myfun([]))
print(a.myfun([]))
```

print out:
[1]
[1]

expected result:
[1]
[2]
...

Comment: What is myfun in a.myfun()? Please be a bit more specific it is not clear what is the probelm.

Comment: I want to change the value of self.number outside the computational graph returned by myfunction, myfun is the graph I think

Comment: Can anybody know how to use K.function(inputs, outputs, updates)?
what I want to fulfill is an updating mechanism